# Why my website cannot read the css and javascript file? It shows failed to load resource (404)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm beginner for PHP. I'm using Wordpress for developing the website. Currently, I'm trying to create my own themes for wordpress. Now, I face the problem is cannot load the css which is in the CSS file as well as javascript. Could someone help me to solve the problem?

header.php

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <script>
    var template_dir_js = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>";
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/skel.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/skel-layers.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/init.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-xlarge.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-mobile.css" />


    </noscript>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="landing">
```

functions.php

```
    <?php
add_theme_support('menus');
function register_theme_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(array( 'primary-menu' => __('Primary Menu')));
}
add_action('init', 'register_theme_menus'); 
function wpt_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-xlarge.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/skel.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-mobile.css'); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_theme_styles'); 
function wpt_theme_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'foundation_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/skel.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init1_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/skel-layers.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init2_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/init.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'init2_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/scrollgress.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.1', true ); 
    }
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'wpt_theme_js'); 
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
<hr> <?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<div id="delimiter">
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNeA6.jpg)
[after modify error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bZ8h.jpg)

Comment: In the `header.php` try putting your scripts inside the `<script>` tags and remove `rel="stylesheet" ` from your scripts tags.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

- Your `style.css` file isn't inside a folder called `css` so update the `<link>` tag to: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/style.css" />`
- `<script>` tags cannot have a `rel="stylesheet"` attribute.
- The `<!-- [if lte IE 8]...` tags are probably also serving from the `css` directory, so also reference the `get_template_directory_url()` in their path.
- It is a good idea to only reference the `css` files in the `<head>` and place the `<script>` tags at the bottom of your file, before the `</body>` tag.

Full Fixed `header.php`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <script>
    var template_dir_js = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>";
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/skel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/skel-layers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/skel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-xlarge.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-desktop.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style-mobile.css" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="landing">
```

Comment: Hi, why it still get the error? (Click at "after modify error" link)

Comment: @FanJane Make sure your wordpress Site URL is configured correctly, see this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL